# como empilhar dados que estou desempilhando de uma pilha?

Tags: c, estrutura-de-dados, stack

Preciso empilhar 5 cores e imprimir da base para o topo em uma nova pilha na seguinte questão:

- (1) **Vermelho**
- (2) **Verde**
- (3) **Azul**
- (4) **Branco**
- (5) **Laranja**

> São cinco pratos coloridos e precisa mantê-los um em cima do outro.
> Você começa colocando o prato de cor vermelha sobre a mesa.
> Este é o primeiro elemento da pilha.
> Em seguida, você coloca o verde em cima do vermelho. Este é
> o segundo elemento da pilha.
> Da mesma forma, você coloca o prato azul seguido do branco
> e, finalmente, o laranja.
> Note que o
> primeiro prato que você inseriu na pilha foi o vermelho, e agora você
> quer ordena-los de forma inversa: 5, 4, 3, 2 e 1.

A partir dessas informações você deverá desenvolver um programa em Linguagem C que execute os seguintes passos:

1. Preencher uma pilha com os cinco pratos citados acima;
2. Imprimir a pilha na ordem em que os elementos foram inseridos (iniciando pela base, e finalizando pelo topo);
3. Desempilhar todos os elementos, inserindo-os em uma segunda estrutura de dados do tipo pilha;
4. Imprimir a nova pilha na ordem em que os elementos foram inseridos (iniciando pela base, e finalizando pelo topo).

esse foi o código que consegui fazer

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define TAMANHO 5

void push(char *valor);
void push2(char *prato);
char *pop();

char vetor[TAMANHO][40];
int posicao = 0;

int main()
{
    push("Verde");
    push("Vermelho");
    push("Marron");
    push("cinza");
    push("branco");
    
    printf("\n");
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
    
    printf("desempilhou o prato: %s\n", pop());
    printf("desempilhou o prato: %s\n", pop());
    printf("desempilhou o prato: %s\n", pop());
    printf("desempilhou o prato: %s\n", pop());
    printf("desempilhou o prato: %s\n", pop());
    
    printf("\n");
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
    
    
}

void push(char *valor)
{
     if(posicao == TAMANHO)
         printf("Estouro de pilha\n");
     else
     {
         strcpy(vetor[posicao],valor);
         posicao++;
         printf("empilhou prato: %s\n", valor);
     }
}

void push2(char *prato)
{
     if(posicao == TAMANHO)
         printf("Estouro de pilha\n");
     else
     {
         strcpy(vetor[posicao],prato);
         posicao++;
         prato = vetor;
         printf("cor: %s", prato);
     }
     
}

char *pop()
{
    if(posicao > 0)
    {
        posicao--;
        return vetor[posicao];
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Pilha vazia\n");
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Nós somos um site de  perguntas e respostas. Poderia por favor nos detelimitar uma pergunta?

Answer (score 1):

Não escreva assim:

```
void push(char *valor)
{
     if(posicao == TAMANHO)
         printf("Estouro de pilha\n");
     else
     {
         strcpy(vetor[posicao],valor);
         posicao++;
         printf("empilhou prato: %s\n", valor);
     }
}

void push2(char *prato)
{
     if(posicao == TAMANHO)
         printf("Estouro de pilha\n");
     else
     {
         strcpy(vetor[posicao],prato);
         posicao++;
         prato = vetor;
         printf("cor: %s", prato);
     }
     
}
```

Uma função para cada pilha para fazer a mesma coisa? E se fossem 12 pilhas?

Tem um exemplo de um programa C que faz isso [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/554281/estrutura-de-dados-pilha-c/554347#554347)

### Adaptando o exemplo para uma pilha de `char[40]`

```
    const char* teste[] =
    { "Verde","Vermelho","Marron","Cinza","Branco"};
```

O exemplo cria uma pilha `orig` com esses valores e depois transfere usando `POP` para outra pilha e mostra as duas pilhas na tela

#### saída do exemplo

```
Teste: ainda vazia
Pilha VAZIA (cap:8):

Teste: primeira pilha
5 elementos (cap:8):
        Verde
        Vermelho
        Marron
        Cinza
        Branco


Tirando os elementos e colocando na outra pilha:


Ao final: pilha original
Pilha VAZIA (cap:8):

Ao final: pilha resultante
5 elementos (cap:8):
        Branco
        Cinza
        Marron
        Vermelho
        Verde
```

#### a pilha

```
#define TAMANHO_ 8
#define LIMITE_ 40

typedef struct
{
    int tam;
    int lim;
    char dado[1 + TAMANHO_][LIMITE_];

} Pilha;

int POP(Pilha*);
int PUSH(const char*, Pilha*);
int TOP(Pilha*,char*);

int mostra(Pilha*, const char*);
```

- `POP` retira um elemento da pilha e retorna o tamanho dela
- `PUSH` insere o elemento fornecido na Pilha e retorna o tamanho dela
- `TOP` copia o valor no topo da pilha para o endereço apontado pelo segundo argumento e retorna 0. Ou um valor negativo em caso de erro.
- um valor negativo no retorno de `POP` e `PUSH` indica erro.
- `mostra` é uma função de teste e mostra o conteúdo da pilha. Para conveniência aceita um título opcional.
- reservar a primeira posição da pilha simplifica muito o programa. Veja no código.

POP tem 4 linhas, PUSH tem 10 e TOP tem 4 apenas.

#### RESUMO

Esse código esvazia uma pilha e ao mesmo tempo copia os valores para a outra. Entenda que passar o endereço da pilha como argumento faz toda a diferença. É o conceito de **encapsulamento**:

```
    for (int i = orig.tam; i > 0; i -= 1)
    {
        TOP(&orig, el);
        POP(&orig);
        PUSH(el, &reversa);
    }
```

Cada pilha tem dentro a informação do tamanho e as funções aceitam o endereço da pilha em que vão atuar. Como é um exemplo de teste nem estamos testando os valores de retorno...

#### o código do exemplo

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define TAMANHO_ 8
#define LIMITE_ 40

typedef struct
{
    int tam;
    int lim;
    char dado[1 + TAMANHO_][LIMITE_];

} Pilha;

int POP(Pilha*);
int PUSH(const char*, Pilha*);
int TOP(Pilha*,char*);

int mostra(Pilha*, const char*);

int main(void)
{
    const char* teste[] =
    { 
    "Verde","Vermelho","Marron","Cinza","Branco"
    };
    Pilha orig = {.tam = 0, .lim = TAMANHO_};
    mostra(&orig, "\nTeste: ainda vazia");
    int res   = 0;
    int n_tst = sizeof(teste) / sizeof(teste[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < n_tst; i += 1)
    {
        res = PUSH((const char*)teste[i], &orig);
        if (res < 1) break;
    }
    mostra(&orig, "\nTeste: primeira pilha");
    // agora tira um por um e poe na outra pilha
    printf(
        "\nTirando os elementos e colocando na outra "
        "pilha:\n\n");
    Pilha reversa = {.tam = 0, .lim = TAMANHO_};
    char  el[LIMITE_];
    for (int i = orig.tam; i > 0; i -= 1)
    {
        TOP(&orig, el);
        POP(&orig);
        PUSH(el, &reversa);
    }
    mostra(&orig, "\nAo final: pilha original");
    mostra(&reversa, "\nAo final: pilha resultante");
    return 0;
}

// tira um cara da pilha, retorna o tamanho
int POP(Pilha* p)
{
    if (p == NULL) return -1;
    if (p->tam == 0) return -2;
    p->tam -= 1;
    return p->tam;
}

// poe um cara na pilha, retorna o tamanho
int PUSH(const char* val, Pilha* p)
{
    if ((p == NULL) || (val==NULL)) return -1;
    if (strlen(val) > LIMITE_ - 1) return -2; // nao cabe
    p->tam += 1;
    if (p->tam > p->lim)
    {
        p->tam -= 1;
        return -3;
    }
    strcpy(p->dado[p->tam], val);
    return p->tam;
}

int TOP(Pilha* p, char* val)
{
    if ((p == NULL) || (val == NULL)) return -1;
    if (p->tam == 0) return -2;
    strcpy(val, p->dado[p->tam]);
    return 0;
}

int mostra(Pilha* p, const char* tit)
{
    if (p == NULL)
    {
        printf("pilha invalida\n");
        return -1;
    }
    if (tit != NULL) printf("%s\n", tit);
    if (p->tam == 0)
    {
        printf("Pilha VAZIA (cap:%d):\n", p->lim);
        return 0;
    }
    printf("%d elementos (cap:%d):\n", p->tam, p->lim);
    for (int i = 1; i < p->tam; i += 1)
        printf("\t%s\n", p->dado[i]);
    printf("\t%s\n\n", p->dado[p->tam]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Eu e mais uma resposta inútil, segundo alguns leitores! Mas ao menos essa discute o problema. E o programa proposto. E tem um exemplo em C. E a saída do exemplo. ;) E tem um link para um exemplo mais simples ainda. Claro, o exemplo foi também marcado como inútil. funny times indeed
arfn

Comment: Eu não acho inútil. Na verdade achei bem escrita e inteligente, mas diariamente tem tanto conteúdo ruim sendo inserido no site que esta soterrando o conteúdo bom. Eu só encontrei a resposta porque ontem eu fiz a edição da pergunta e decidi revisar minha edição e aproveitei para ler a resposta.