# Estrutura de Dados/Pilha - C

Tags: c

2 dias quebrando a cabeça e não consegui avançar com o código.

> 1 - Empilho 2 - Desempilho 3 - O item que foi desempilhado tem que ser
> adicionado na Pilha2.

Não estou conseguindo verificar o envio do item desempilhado para a nova pilha. Do jeito que está, até imprime os valores(1 até 5) devido uma variável **AUX** dentro de um FOR, a meu ver não está correto. Se passo pilha2.topo imprime(0 até 4) e não de 1 até 5 que foi desempilhado.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define tamanho 5

typedef struct tipo_pilha{
    int dados[tamanho];
    int ini;
    int topo;
}tipo_pilha;

tipo_pilha pilha;
tipo_pilha pilha2;

void empilha(int elemento){
    if(pilha.topo == tamanho){
        printf("Pilha Cheia.\n");
        system("PAUSE");
    }
    else
    {
        pilha.dados[pilha.topo] = elemento;
        pilha.topo++;
    }
}
int desempilha(){
    int elemento;
    if(pilha.topo == pilha.ini){
        printf("Pilha NULL.\n");
        system("PAUSE");
    }
    else
    {
        pilha.topo--;
        elemento = pilha.dados[pilha.topo];
        return elemento;
    }
}
void empilha2(int elemento){
    if(pilha2.topo == tamanho){
        printf("Pilha Cheia.\n");
        system("PAUSE");
    }
    else{
    pilha2.dados[pilha2.topo] = elemento;
    pilha2.topo++;
    }
}
int main(){
    printf("%d \n", pilha.topo);

    int aux;
    printf("### Empilhando Pilha 1 ###\n\n");
    for(int i=1; i<=5; i++){
        aux = i;
        printf("Empilhando o %d.\n", aux);
        empilha(aux);
    }
    printf("%d \n", pilha.topo);
    printf("### Desempilhando Pilha 1 ###\n\n");
    for(int i=1; i<=5; i++){
        aux = desempilha();
        printf("Desempilhou: %d.\n", aux);
    }
    printf("%d \n", pilha.topo);

    printf("### Empilhando 2 Pilha ### \n\n");
    for(int i= 1; i<= 5;i++){
        aux = i;
        printf("Empilhando o %d.\n", aux);
        empilha2(aux);
}
    printf("%d \n", pilha2.topo);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

- Você não precisa criar uma função para empilhar cada pilha individualmente se tomar a pilha desejada como argumento da função `empilha`.
- É ideal que a `main` retorne 0 no final da execução.
- No primeiro dentro da `main`, você não precisa copiar a variável `i` para outra variável, basta usá-la diretamente.

Dito isso, posso prosseguir para sua pergunta. Se você quer desempilhar uma pilha para dentro de outra, você teria que fazer algo assim:

```
while (pilha.ini != pilha.topo)
    empilha2(desempilha());
```

Answer (score -1):

Pode dar certo do modo como está fazendo, mas não está bom: imagine se fossem 12 pilhas e considere quantas funções iria escrever para desempilhar. E quantas variáveis para controlar...

Vou deixar um exemplo da maneira comum de escrever isso.

#### Sobre o programa original

- a `struct pilha` poderia ser anônima
- considere a convenção de reservar algo diferente, como a primeira letra em maiúscula, para os tipos definidos no programa
- considere a convenção de usar apenas maiúsculas no nome de constantes
- se a pilha é estática tem um tamanho definido desde sempre, então talvez não precise de duas variáveis para controlar isso.
- `pilha` e `pilha2` não deveriam ser globais.
- não misture lógica e `printf()` e muito menos `system()` ou pausas no meio dos comandos ou os testes vão ficar muito lentos e o uso impossível.
- entenda que as operaçoes com pilhas tem nomes consagrados:

  - POP, PUSH e TOP retiram um elemento, inserem um elemento e retornam o elemento no topo da pilha, nessa ordem.

### O EXEMPLO

#### a `Pilha`

```
typedef struct
{
    int tam;
    int lim;
    int dados[1 + TAMANHO_];

} Pilha;

int POP(Pilha*);
int PUSH(int, Pilha*);
int TOP(Pilha*);

int mostra(Pilha*, const char*);
```

- `POP` retira um elemento da pilha e retorna o tamanho dela
- `PUSH` insere o elemento fornecido na Pilha e retorna o tamanho dela
- `TOP` retorna o valor no topo da pilha ou `INT_MIN` se a pilha estiver vazia.
- um valor negativo no retorno de `POP` e `PUSH` indica erro. `INT_MIN` indica erro em `TOP`, mas a pilha pode ter esse valor então errno é usado e indica nesse caso `ERANGE` ou `EINVAL`
- `mostra` é uma função de teste e mostra o conteúdo da pilha. Para conveniência aceita um título opcional.
- reservar a primeira posição da pilha simplifica muito o programa. Veja no código.

#### `main` para o teste

- O exemplo cria uma pilha `orig` e insere valores aleatórios até dar erro. O erro, claro, deve ser ela estar cheia.
- uma nova pilha, `reversa` é criada e os elementos são retirados da pilha `orig` e colocados nessa
- ao final o programa mostra as duas pilhas

```
int main(void)
{
    srand(220529);
    Pilha orig = {.tam = 0, .lim = TAMANHO_};
    mostra(&orig, "\nTeste: ainda vazia");
    int res = 0;
    while (0 <= (res = PUSH(rand() % 100, &orig))){};  // ate dar erro
    mostra(&orig, "\nTeste: deve estar lotada");
    // agora tira um por um e poe na outra pilha
    printf( "\nTirando os elementos e colocando na outra "
        "pilha:\n\n");
    Pilha reversa = {.tam = 0, .lim = TAMANHO_};
    for (int i = orig.tam; i > 0; i -= 1)
    {
        int el = TOP(&orig);
        POP(&orig);
        PUSH(el, &reversa);
    }
    mostra(&orig, "\nAo final: pilha original");
    mostra(&reversa, "pilha nova");
    return 0;
}
```

#### saída do exemplo

```
Teste: ainda vazia
0 elementos (cap:8):    [  vazia ]

Teste: deve estar lotada
8 elementos (cap:8):    [ 65, 15, 38, 24, 80, 73, 77, 82 ]


Tirando os elementos e colocando na outra pilha:


Ao final: pilha original
0 elementos (cap:8):    [  vazia ]
pilha nova
8 elementos (cap:8):    [ 82, 77, 73, 80, 24, 38, 15, 65 ]
```

Esse trecho

```
    while (0 <= (res = PUSH(rand() % 100, &orig))){};
```

por exemplo enche a pilha com valores aleatórios entre 0 e 99. Podia ser escrito apenas

```
    while (0 <= PUSH(rand() % 100, &orig));
```

já que `PUSH()` vai retornar algo positivo (o tamanho) em caso de sucesso. E esse é um programa de teste e não se espera outro erro que não seja *"pilha cheia"*.

```
    Pilha reversa = {.tam = 0, .lim = TAMANHO_};
    for (int i = orig.tam; i > 0; i -= 1)
    {
        int el = TOP(&orig);
        POP(&orig);
        PUSH(el, &reversa);
    }
```

Essa é a maneira comum de transportar os caras de uma pilha para a outra. Claro que por definição ao final a pilha nova vai estar cheia e a original vazia e essas linhas

```
    mostra(&orig, "\nAo final: pilha original");
    mostra(&reversa, "pilha nova");
```

fazem o teste sem *stress*

#### O código do exemplo

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define TAMANHO_ 8

typedef struct
{
    int tam;
    int lim;
    int dados[1 + TAMANHO_];

} Pilha;

int POP(Pilha*);
int PUSH(int, Pilha*);
int TOP(Pilha*);

int mostra(Pilha*, const char*);

int main(void)
{
    srand(220529);
    Pilha orig = {.tam = 0, .lim = TAMANHO_};
    mostra(&orig, "\nTeste: ainda vazia");
    int res = 0;
    while (0 <= (res = PUSH(rand() % 100, &orig))){};  // ate dar erro
    mostra(&orig, "\nTeste: deve estar lotada");
    // agora tira um por um e poe na outra pilha
    printf( "\nTirando os elementos e colocando na outra "
        "pilha:\n\n");
    Pilha reversa = {.tam = 0, .lim = TAMANHO_};
    for (int i = orig.tam; i > 0; i -= 1)
    {
        int el = TOP(&orig);
        POP(&orig);
        PUSH(el, &reversa);
    }
    mostra(&orig, "\nAo final: pilha original");
    mostra(&reversa, "pilha nova");
    return 0;
}

// tira um cara da pilha, retorna o tamanho
int POP(Pilha* p)
{
    if (p == NULL) return -1;
    if (p->tam == 0) return -2;
    p->tam -= 1;
    return p->tam;
}

// poe um cara na pilha, retorna o tamanho
int PUSH(int el, Pilha* p)
{
    if (p == NULL) return -1;
    p->tam += 1;
    if (p->tam > p->lim)
    {
        p->tam -= 1;
        return -2;
    }
    p->dados[p->tam] = el;
    return p->tam;
}

int TOP(Pilha* p)
{
    if (p == NULL)
    {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return INT_MIN;
    }
    if (p->tam == 0)
    {
        errno = ERANGE;
        return INT_MIN;
    }
    return p->dados[p->tam];
}

int mostra(Pilha* p, const char* tit)
{
    if (p == NULL)
    {
        printf("pilha invalida\n");
        return -1;
    }
    if (tit != NULL) printf("%s\n", tit);
    printf("%d elementos (cap:%d):\t[ ", p->tam, p->lim);
    if (p->tam == 0)
    {
        printf(" vazia ]\n");
        return 0;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < p->tam; i += 1)
        printf("%d, ", p->dados[i]);
    printf("%d ]\n\n", p->dados[p->tam]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Eu e mais uma resposta inútil! Mas ao menos essa discute o problema. E o programa proposto. E tem um exemplo em C. E a saída do exemplo. ;) **funny times indeed**